# Eventhandler with classes

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

i've some div's with the same class. When I click one of those div's, I want change the display from other div's to 'block'. I'm currently using inline javascript, but I want to do it without inline javascript. What I have now:

```
<div class="test_a" id="example_a" onclick="testfunction(this)"></div>
<div class="test_a" id="example_b" onclick="testfunction(this)"></div>
<div class="test_a" id="example_c" onclick="testfunction(this)"></div>
<div class="test_a" id="example_d" onclick="testfunction(this)"></div>
<div class="test_a" id="example_e" onclick="testfunction(this)"></div>

<div class="test_b" id="example_a_test"></div>
<div class="test_b" id="example_b_test"></div>
<div class="test_b" id="example_c_test"></div>
<div class="test_b" id="example_d_test"></div>
<div class="test_b" id="example_e_test"></div>
```

my function in javascript:

```
function testfunction(x){
var example = document.getElementById(x.id + "_test");
example.style.display = 'block';
}
```

So when you click on the div with id example_a, I want to change the display from example_a_test.

working example: http://pastehtml.com/view/c63rmz6tw.html

Now, how to do this with eventhandlers?

Comment: onclick is an event handler, see e.g. http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_event_handlers.cfm. Do you mean something different?

Comment: Ok, I know onclick is an event handler, but I don't exactly know how I can make the example I made without using inline javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `click` event handler that you can use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

var init = (function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
      i = 0;
  for (i = divs.length; i--;) {
    listener(i);
  }
  function listener(i) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var id = this.getAttribute('id'),
          idTest = id + '_test',
          testElem = document.getElementById(idTest),
          divClass = this.getAttribute('class');
      if (divClass === 'test_a') {
        testElem.style.display = 'block';
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
});
```

Make sure that your `test_b` elements are set to `display: none;` in your CSS.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pb9d4/12/).

Comment: thanks! but for some reason, it doesn't work :s    :
http://pastehtml.com/view/c63u0u3z8.html

and I really don't know how the javascript you posted does work, don't know if you have time for this, but could you explain what's going on?

Comment: Can you post your code to jsfiddle.net? pastehtml.com is blocked here at work.

Comment: Basically, I've created a cross-browser event listener function (`listen`) that you pass in parameters to for event handlers. It listens for `load` and then calls `init`. `init` grabs the `div` elements and passes them through a `for` loop which then invokes another function which assign click handlers to each `div`. If the `div` has a class of `test_a`, then it sets the CSS to `display: block` for the test elements. You'll need to put this into an external JS file and call it within your `head` element.

Comment: Thanks! btw, you were talking about cross-browser, this has only to work in chrome, does that mean the javascript can be simpler?

Comment: I've now made the same but with mouseover and mouseout, is this the right way to do it? http://jsfiddle.net/Pb9d4/8/    ow, it only has to work in chrome ;). Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: You're welcome! If it only has to work in Chrome, then you can eliminate the `listen` function. I can update my answer if you need me to.

Comment: Okay, changes made. Also, here is a fork of your `mouseover` and `mouseout` function: http://jsfiddle.net/uFQSg/1/

Comment: ok, maybe my last question, why you are using so many vars? is it good to do that? oh, and can't you just change `var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')` to this: `  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('test_a')` and remove if function? jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uFQSg/15/

Comment: Whatever works for you. My original answer kept cross-browser inconsistencies in mind. `document.getElementsByClassName` does not work in IE8 and below. You could also use `document.querySelector('.class-name')`.

Comment: ok, beside that, about the vars, why you are using so many of? is it good to do that? is that better? I mean, i'm just a noob that started learning javascript...

Comment: but awesome help you gave me, I don't know how I can thank you!

Comment: It helps me organize my code and to have those vars cached. You're absolutely right about removing that `if` statement. Again, I was writing for cross-browser reasons, and those methods are not supported by IE8 and below.

Comment: You're absolutely right cross-browser support is very important!
in this case, it only has to work for chrome, so I was able to shrink the javascript to this: http://jsfiddle.net/YC4VQ/

thanks for your help, again!
have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Is jquery an option?

```
$('.test_a').click(function(){
    $('#' + this.id + '_test').css('display','block'); (or even .show())
});
```

Comment: I prefer not to use jQuery, to understand what's really going on. but thanks for your answer!